# How does irc and Xchat communicate?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, irc, xchat2, hexchat

Does anyone know how Xchat communicate with IRC server? I'm looking for a IRC request message or Xchat request message with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XChat, like all IRC clients, communicates with the IRC server using the IRC protocol, which have specification in [RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459) and [RFC2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812).

XChat also has a "Raw Log" option hidden in it's menu under `Window` -> `Raw Log...` which you can use to see all the traffic between XChat and the server.